# Como verificar se uma Database SQLite3 é valida?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Eu estava testando e vendo o que acontece se o android criar uma database com valores errados de entrada.

Por exemplo, se eu sem querer digitasse NOOT ao invés de NOT ou INTEGET ao invés de INTEGER, eu esperava que o SQL apontasse um erro de retorno dizendo que as palavras chaves do SQL estavam incorretas. Ou pelos menos, que a entrada é invalida.

Mas não é isso que acontece. Veja esse snippet:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE asd (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, breed TEXT NOT NULL, gender INTEGET NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
sqlite> .schema asd
CREATE TABLE asd (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, breed TEXT NOT NULL, gender INTEGET NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
sqlite>
```

Veja que gender eu propositalmente inseri o tipo de dados como INTEGET ao invés de INTEGER e ao que parece o SQL aceitou.

Outro exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE qwe (_id INTEGET PRIMARY KEY);

sqlite> INSERT INTO qwe (_ID) VALUES (0);
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> SELECT * FROM qwe;
_id       
----------
0         
sqlite>
```

Veja que mais uma vez, ao invés de usar INTEGER eu coloquei INTEGET e o SQL não informa erro. Ele adiciona a informação, mesmo sendo ao meu ver, um tipo de dado invalido.

Minha pergunta é, se o SQL processa entradas com erro, como verificar se minha database é valida ao criar aplicativos?

Answer (score 3):

Como você poder ler no [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3), essa é uma característica e não um *BUG* do *SQLite*. Diferente de outros bancos de dados, como *MySQL* por exemplo, o *SQLite* não utiliza uma tipagem rígida.

Ao invés disso, é utilizado um sistema de tipagem genérica que está associado ao seu valor e não necessariamente ao tipo da coluna.

Isso permite que o sistema utilize o que eles chamam de [afinidade de tipo](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity). Esse sistema irá converter os valores da tabela *(ver exemplo abaixo)*.

**Exemplo:**

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE asd (_id INTEGER);
sqlite>
sqlite> INSERT INTO asd VALUES ("a");
sqlite>
sqlite> INSERT INTO asd VALUES (123);
sqlite>
sqlite> INSERT INTO asd VALUES (456.789);
sqlite>
sqlite> SELECT * FROM asd;
        a
        123
        456.789
sqlite>
sqlite> SELECT typeof (_id) FROM asd;
        text
        integer
        real
sqlite>
```

<sup>Referência: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html</sup>

> Como verificar se minha database é valida ao criar aplicativos?

Como mencionei na primeira oração, sua estrutura sempre será válida para o *SQLite*, mas se você quiser um controle mais rígido, é necessário fazer uma validação, apenas isso. Você pode utilizar [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/sMkioY/1) para validar a estrutura da tabela e utilizar comparações antes de inserir um registro na tabela.

Comment: Em SQLite você pode criar colunas não tipadas, inclusive. Os valores inteiros são tratados de maneira especial na chave primária, se for `autoincrement` se não me engano.